# how to extract specific content from webpage using jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I need to extract ONLY those publications from the web page http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/r/Rao:Rahul.html, where the first author is Rahul Rao.

I have tried the following code ,but it doesn't give me any output.

```
for( Element element : doc.select("table span.this-person.title") ){
System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

What do I need to get the preferred output? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please guys help me out with this.I am stuck over here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will give you the expected output ..see if it helps you !!

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/r/Rao:Rahul.html").get();
        Elements span = doc.select(("div[class=data]"));

```
    //System.out.println(span.tagName("span"));
    for (Element src : span) {

        for(int i=0;i<src.childNodeSize();i++){
            if(src.childNodes().get(0).toString().contains("Rahul Rao")){
                if(src.childNodes().get(i).toString().contains("<span class=\"title\">")){
                    System.out.println(src.childNodes().get(i));
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to extract the publications posted on the page and got some success .

The code is as follows:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/r/Rao:Rahul.html").get();
    Elements span = doc.select("span");
    for (Element src : span) {
        if (src.tagName().equals("span")){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print( src.ownText() );
        }
    }
```

Please have a look if it helps !!

Comment: But it gives me all the publications of Rahul Rao..I need only those publications where Rahul Rao is the first author.

Comment: Can you tell me what should be your expected output or in which publications Rahul Rao is the first author.