# How to get some specific content on a webpage by using Jsoup

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

I'm using jsoup. And I want to get the content of only [this](http://131940.qld.gov.au/Road-Conditions.aspx?tab=incident#incidents) url. I mean, I want only the contents of **Incidents** tab only; not other page contents. But now the content I'm getting is the content of whole page other than this tab. I tried to follow even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174503/2069130) but not still succeeded. Looking for some kind of even better help if someone have knowledge about Jsoup.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fetch you the required results

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(
          "http://131940.qld.gov.au/Road-Conditions.aspx?tab=incident#incidents")
          .userAgent(
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36"
           ).timeout(0) .followRedirects(true) .execute().parse();
          System.out.println(document.select("#incidents").html());
```

Comment: Can you please tell me about how it works actually. I need to learn more about Jsoup.